# Python: Using the xlrd module to get a cell's row,column

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am using the xlrd module for handling data in excel (if there is any better module please advise!). Is there any way to extract a cell's row and column information? Are there any members or methods besides introducing a counter? This question was asked a year ago but didn't receive much attention.

Also did anyone find any good API detailing this module? All I found was this: http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Rowinfo-class

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give a code example? It's not clear. Yo usually need the row and columns to get the cell in the first place, so the other way around is weird.